# Viewing return code in debugger when the value is not assigned to a variable

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

In case of the following code:

**da.Fill(ds)**

Is it possible to view the return code from the Fill method in the Visual Studio debugger?

If the following is the case:

**rc = da.Fill(ds)**

then it's not a problem, as the variable rc gets the value assigned, but there are cases when I can't modify the code and re-build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's displayed in the "Autos" window. Debug/Windows/Autos

At least for C++, doesn't seem to work for C#.

Comment: In the Autos window (for C++), what is the name of the node that shows the return code that you mention?  (I am using VB.)

Comment: Todd, in C++ the Autos window automatically creates a line "Fill returns".  Alternatively, for C++, you could look at the EAX register.  Return values are normally passed via the EAX register.  Don't know if this is the same for VB, but you could try it.

Comment: Yes, EAX use seems to be a universal convention, thank you Patrick.

Comment: `eax` is for x86. Use `ret0` for Itanium and `rax` for x64.